# How can I declare custom pipes globally for test specs?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine

I have a translation pipe that I use across all my angular components. 
As so: `{{'Welcome_Message' | translate}}`

I don't want to have to declare it in each of my spec files, so I've been looking for a way to declare it globally, but I can't seem to find anything. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Currently I'm copying and pasting a simple mock pipe across all my specs, but it feels so dirty having the same block of code in all these files.

Comment: did you create a module for the custom pipe?

Comment: @ram12393 Yep. The pipe works globally when the app is run, but it can't be found when I run `ng test`.